# Cannot use class from another file (c++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, class

I'm trying to access another class from main .cpp file.

here's my class:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "Entity.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace sf;
using namespace std;

#ifndef INCLUDE_PLAYER_H
#define INCLUDE_PLAYER_H

class Player : Entity
{
   // lots of stuff here
};
#endif
```

and as I put #include `"Player.h"` to main.cpp I get an Error: cannot open source file "Player.h".
What's wrong?

P.S. Is there any other way to use class from another file not using headers?

Comment: are they in the same folder? are they in the same namespace?

Comment: @pennstatephil they're in the same folder, but in different "filters", that's how it's called in Visual Studio. Is that the issue? Anyway if I put them both into the same, it still doesn't work.

Comment: I use visual studio regularly, but I haven't heard of different "filters". Essentially, the main class doesn't know where to look for player.

Comment: @pennstatephil that's what divides source file in Source Files when you create additional "folders"

Comment: @arcadia "filters" just control  what you can/can't see when you're browsing project files.  `#include` bypasses that.  If you open a command prompt, find main.cpp.  Is that the same main.cpp you see in visual studio and is player.h in the same folder?  PS - please fix your header, RARELY include includes in a header, NEVER outside the `#pragma once` you aren't using properly.  And NEVER include stdafx.h in a header...

Comment: @ebyrob fixed, thanks. I'm new to c++ and so I'm bad at it right now :| The files are in the same folder, right.

Comment: @arcadia I think you're going to have to do something like zip the project.  My guess is you've got more than one main.cpp floating around and the project file is kinda murky.  There are cases where I've had to put $(SolutionDir) and friends in include path, but you really shouldn't be hitting that on a simple project.  Note: If you can't find "player.h" the contents of "player.h" are pretty much irrelevant.  Also, error should be: cannot open include file "Player.h".

Answer (score 2):

`Player.h` is not in the include path for `main.cpp`. Are these in the same folder?

Also, you should not do `using namespace` in headers, as all files that include this header will also import these namespaces, which can only cause trouble. The best idea is to keep using fully-qualified names (at least for `std`, but also for `sf`).

Comment: thanks! Yes, the files are in the same folder. Btw, is there a way to avoid using headers while trying to use classes from other files?

Comment: @arcadia you could avoid extra .cpp files (ugly).  Headers are what bind different C and C++ modules together.  There's really no avoiding them.